# If Custom Field Value : display, if not display another Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm trying to display 2 different values on my wordpress website : [skuar.com](http://www.skuar.com)
It should be, after clicking on any thumbnail (center logo)

If there is a field value in ('music') : display

else, display value in ('image') field

It actually dosen't work, is the code good ?

```
<?php
$music = get_field('music');
$image = get_field('image');

if ($music!=''){ ?>
<iframe width="600" height="166" scrolling="no" class="lightbox" class="frame" id="featherlight" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=<?php the_field('music'); ?>&amp;color=1b1e25&amp;theme_color=1b1e25&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe> 

<?php } else { ?>

<img src="<?php $image ?>" />
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php } ?>

<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails');
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `get_field()` is empty, it actually returns *false*, not an empty string. So your code is always running the iframe because `$music` is never an empty string (it's either false or some value you set). Try this:

```
<?php if( get_field( 'music' ) ): ?>
  <iframe width="600" height="166" scrolling="no" class="lightbox" class="frame" id="featherlight" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=<?php the_field( 'music' ); ?>&amp;color=1b1e25&amp;theme_color=1b1e25&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
<?php else: ?>
  <img src="<?php the_field( 'image' ); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. I have tried different option but still doesn't work, I don't know why.